# Add an element to a const set

Tags: javascript

How would you add an element to an existing `Set` when defining it? For example, if I have:

```
const s1 = Set([1,2,3]);
const elem = 4;
const s2 = s1 + elem; // ?
```

Is using the spread operator (`...`) the correct way to do this?

```
s2 = new Set([...s, elem]);
```

Or is there another/better approach?

Comment: I'd do `const s2 = new Set(s1).add(elem);`

Comment: @ChrisG -- Oh I see, since `const` only cares about the re-assignment of the object, and not actually modifying the elements. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`Set#add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add). Using `const` here only prevents setting `s1` to another value, but does not make the `Set` immutable.

```js
const s1 = new Set([1,2,3]);
const elem = 4;
s1.add(elem);
console.log([...s1]);
```

Comment: thanks, just to clarify is `Set#add` the same as `Set.add` or why is the `#` used? Sorry if a dumb question.

Comment: @David542 People use `#` to clarify it's an instance method.